# Icons not showing in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

i am creating a jQuery mobile application.Icons doesn't appear in any of my page.

here is the code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.min.css" /> 
<script src="script/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="script/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
```

But when I using CDN hosted file its working fine. Why should this happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you using it locally, then you will have to download 4 more files from images directory:
icons-18-black.png , icons-36-black.png, icons-18-white.png and icons-36-white.png. These are the four image files jquery css uses to display those icons. Download them and save it inside "images" folder and sharing the same root folder as that of your css file. And it would be working fine coz, CDN will host these images for you.

[Dowload Link](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/images/icons-36-black.png)

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using a internal package. The internal package must be getting the icons from your pc. You should have to include the whole files in the correct directories. Or try including this hosted libraries

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided enough information in your question. Your error could be for many reasons such as:

- If you're using an icon font:

  - is the font uploaded to the right directory?
  - Is the character you're calling supported in that font?
  - Is the `font-size` of your icons set to a visible value?
- If you're using jQuery's included icons:

  - Have you uploaded them to the right directory?
  - Are you pointing your URL to the correct location to load them?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with the version of jQuery Mobile that I downloaded.

I had downloaded the code from a "**jquerymobile.jqGrid-Trial.zip**" file.  On my laptop, the jqGrid Mobile icons looked fine, but on an iPhone or Android device, they'd be badly offset.

[image]

My solution was to modify part of the **jquery.mobile.css** file to look like this:

```
.ui-icon-plus, .ui-icon-minus, .ui-icon-delete, .ui-icon-arrow-r,
.ui-icon-arrow-l, .ui-icon-arrow-u, .ui-icon-arrow-d, .ui-icon-check,
.ui-icon-gear, .ui-icon-refresh, .ui-icon-forward, .ui-icon-back,
.ui-icon-grid, .ui-icon-star, .ui-icon-alert, .ui-icon-info, .ui-icon-home, .ui-icon-bars, .ui-icon-edit,
.ui-icon-search, .ui-icon-searchfield:after, 
.ui-icon-checkbox-off, .ui-icon-checkbox-on, .ui-icon-radio-off, .ui-icon-radio-on {
    background-image: url(images/icons-18-white.png);
    -moz-background-size: 776px 18px;
    -o-background-size: 776px 18px;
    -webkit-background-size: 776px 18px;
    background-size: 776px 18px;
}
```

(Previously, it had a different background image name in there, and had a quoted image width of 864px, rather than 776px.)

Btw, to find this solution, I actually ignored the .zip file I'd downloaded from the jQuery website, looked at jqGrid's own example (which *did* work fine on a device), then compared the "**jquery-mobile-1.2.0.css**" file which they'd chosen to use:

[Working jQuery Grid demo](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/mobile/indexhtml.html)

Hope this helps.